# Can tree column be hidden programmatically in TreeTableView of JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, treetableview

I have a useful TreeTableView GUI view definition builder and would like to use in on tabular data where I don't need drill downs. I tried ...

```
m_treeTableView.getTreeColumn().setVisible(false);
```

... but it doesn't hide the tree column. Any help?

Comment: `treeTableColumn.getColumns().remove(columnToRemove)`. But note if you remove the `treeColumn`, it seems the user would not be able to expand/collapse tree nodes (though I don’t know the exact behavior in this case).

Comment: Also: *”on tabular data where I don’t need drill downs”*. Why not just use a plain `TableView`?

Comment: @James_D Thanks James. I have a highly functional TreeTable GUI based view builder that can easily define very complex columns. I seldom need just tables so wanted to  reuse this module when I do.

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks Kleopatra. This is from an ancient code, very complex but reliable and proven in production - Unix/Motif from 90ties, ported to SWING, now ported to JavaFX, so we follow the old style. And the issue is just in this one line. Pls see my findings below.

Comment: wow, 30 yrs - quite a distance to drag code ;)

Answer (score -1):

`getTreeColumn` appears to be returning null regardless of the thread or delayed execution I call it from. However, the column exists at index zero in the `TreeTableView` vector of columns. Hiding it by index works fine but gives unpredictable results if drill-down is defined.

However, `TreeTableView` hides the column automatically and elegantly if no drill-down is defined - logical behaviour and exactly what I need.

Edit: `getTreeColumn` returns null even if the column is not null, but is at its default position, leftmost place. Otherwise it returns the column.

Comment: hmm .. this seems to be an extremely unusual issue particular to nothing else but your (possibly suboptimally, at least for javafx) implemented context ;)